# C# DataGridView not updating database on keyboard return

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with a `CellEndEdit` function that updates my database. However, it only works if the user clicks off the edited cell onto a different row. If the user presses Return on the keyboard, the change is lost.

I have looked at the variables in debug mode and found that pressing Return does set everything the same as clicking the next row. Any ideas would be great!

Update Method:

```
private void Grd_RawLedger_UserDeletedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    raw_LedgerTableAdapter.Update(belvan_GL_EEA_M12DataSet.Raw_Ledger);
    this.raw_LedgerTableAdapter.Fill(this.belvan_GL_EEA_M12DataSet.Raw_Ledger);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the `RowValidated` Event instead of the `CellEndEdit` Event?

This should do what you are asking, the only big difference is that instead of saving per cell change it will save per row change. You would also need to make sure that you are only saving things that have changed.